# Refreshing multiple partials with polling in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say I have a list of statuses that might look like this:

```
ul#list
  - @list_items.each do |item|
    li.loading Item #{item.id} - Status: #{item.status}
    li Item #{item.id} - Status: #{item.status}
    li Item #{item.id} - Status: #{item.status}
    li.loading Item #{item.id} - Status: #{item.status}
```

Which renders me:

```
Item 1 - Status: Loading
Item 2 - Status: Finished
Item 3 - Status: Finished
Item 4 - Status: Loading
```

What I would like to do is periodically poll for changes on **individual** list items and refresh them if the status has changed. So far I was able to get away with refreshing the whole list:

```
ul#list
  == render 'status_list', list_items: @list_items
```

Coffee:

```
if $('.loading').length > 0
  setInterval (=>
    @refreshListPartial()
  ), 5000
```

Where `@refreshListPartial` is an AJAX function that hits the Rails Controller which then goes on to refresh the whole list partial:

```
$("#list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'status_list', locals: { list_items: @list_items } ) %>");
```

But how would one go in order to check the state of `individual` list items on the page and refresh only them? I know that React would probably be a much easier solution for this task, but is it even possible to accomplish with Rails without jumping over a dozen hoops? Another thing that came to mind is `ActionCable` (I'm using Rails 5), but opening a perma-connection for this functionality seems to be an overkill, I'd rather prefer polling.

**Update**

Just thinking out loud. So to refresh multiple partials instead of one I'll need to arrive to this in my .js.erb file:

```
<%- @items.each do |item| %>
  $("#list-item-<%= item.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item', locals: { list_item: item } ) %>");
<% end %>
```

The view should now look like:

```
ul#list
  @list_items.each do |item|
    == render 'list_item', list_item: @list_item
```

So what's left is the ajax function that should get the ids' of the list items that are needed to be refreshed and send them to the controller as an array.

Comment: I guess ActionCable will be a better option as it is very easy to implement in Rails 5. But still it depends on how many active users does your website have at any point in time as DB will be taking that many hits. If you still prefer polling you can run a timer which checks for the status and then updates the view accordingly and then clears the timer.

Comment: I don't think polling over each of this statuses is a good idea.Wouldn't that mean if you have 5 list items and 5 active users your server gets about 25 requests? Would be best to poll with a timer in the active page and store the changes of the whole list in a service or something bound to each list item, or use ActionCable. You can let react or your front end framework take care of updating each single status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing an extension of what I myself proposed in the question update.

Frontend code that checks whether some partials need to be refreshed based on their data-tags:

```
class JobRequestPartialReload
  constructor: ->
    checkForRunningJobs = ->
      if $('.poll_for_changes').length > 0
        @arr = []
        $('.poll_for_changes').each (index, element) =>
            @arr.push(element.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id)
        sendDataToRails()

    sendDataToRails = ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/jobs/refresh_list"
        method: "POST"
        data: {jobRequestList: @arr}

    setInterval (=>
      checkForRunningJobs()
    ), 10000

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', new JobRequestPartialReload
```

Controller:

```
  def refresh_list
    ajax_data = params[:jobRequestList].map(&:to_i)
    @job_requests = JobRequest.includes(...).where(id: ajax_data)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Finally, the JS.erb file:

```
<% @job_requests.each do |job| %>
  <% case job.state %>
  <% when 'initiated' %>
    // don't care
  <% when 'active' %>
    visibleStatus = $('#job-id-<%= job.id %> .status-list').text()
    if (visibleStatus == 'initiated') {
      $('#job-id-<%= job.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'job_requests/shared/job_request', locals: { job: job } ) %>");
  <% else %>
    // failed, completed, etc.
    $('#job-id-<%= job.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'job_requests/shared/job_request', locals: { job: job } ) %>");
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Answer update**

I later added js code that checked whether certain partials were in the actual user viewport, and checked only them, at the rate of 5-10 seconds. This greatly reduced the number of queries each client was sending.